# Simultaneously Open, write and save multiple files separately

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I created a python code to open multiple files and edit them and finally save each one separately

the first out file is ok, but after that, the size of the other files increases one by one.

```
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Test')
list_Files = []

date = datetime.now()
result = []
counter = 0
cnt = 0
for single_file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Test') :
    list_Files.append(single_file)
    print(single_file)
    with open(single_file, encoding='utf-8') as fn:
        for line in fn.readlines():
            counter+=1
            result.append(json.loads(line))                  
    cnt+=1
    print(cnt)
    json_file = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Out\\tst_'+f"{str(single_file)}{cnt}"'.json'
    with open(json_file, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Comment: what exactly is your issue?

Comment: the input files the same size, also take more time for each one after the first file

Comment: and what do you get in the output files? What's extra? You are not resetting `result` after you open a new file, so that might be the issue

Comment: if I run each file separately without a loop give me the same size for all files,

but when I run the code I think it damage the previous file with the new one

Comment: I just told you, that you are not resetting result, so each new file will have the contents of the previous one. add `result = []` after you open each file with `with open() as fn`

Comment: Solved, Thank you dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the results array before looping over all your files. While looping over your files you append the results array, making this array longer `result.append(json.loads(line))`. Then, within your file loop you write the results array to your json file. Therefore, each new json file receives a longer results array, and will therefore have a larger file size.

If you initialize/reset your results array within your file loop you be good. See the example code below.

```
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Test')
list_Files = []

date = datetime.now()
# result = [] removed the results array here
counter = 0
cnt = 0
for single_file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Test') :
    result = [] # initialize/reset the results array here
    list_Files.append(single_file)
    print(single_file)
    with open(single_file, encoding='utf-8') as fn:
        for line in fn.readlines():
            counter+=1
            result.append(json.loads(line))                  
    cnt+=1
    print(cnt)
    json_file = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Out\\tst_'+f"{str(single_file)}{cnt}"'.json'
    with open(json_file, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(result, outfile)
```